# How do I solve this recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

How do I solve the following recurrence relation:

```
T(n)=4T(n-1) - 3T(n-2)
```

I tried using substitution but failed as I was unable to find any "general" i-th term for it. 
Any help?

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention the base case:

```
T(0)=0
T(1)=2
```

Comment: What are the base cases, for example $T(0) = ?, T(1) = ?$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Comment: Do you know about how to solve recurrence relationsw via the characteristic polynomial? That provides a straight solution.

Comment: Also, $$\frac{T(n)-T(n-1)}{T(n-1)-T(n-2)}=3$$

Comment: Perhaps there's one or more number $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^n=4\alpha^{n-1}-3\alpha^{n-2}$? (If there are two such numbers, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, it's easy to see that $T(n)=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n$ solves the recurrence for all $A,B$.)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I know the general characteristic polynomial method, but how does one solve using the ratio of successive terms?

Comment: @taninamdar, I have added the base cases in the question.

Comment: Using my previous comment: $T(n)=3^n-1$ works. (Try to figure out how to solve it. Use my previous comment as a hint.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw, shouldn't it be, T(n)=3^n only, (without the minus one). I didn't get the minus one. Did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: @AkshayArora $T(n)=3^n$ also fits the recurrence, but it doesn't fit the initial conditions (i.e. that $T(0)=0$ and $T(1)=2$). / I'm assuming you did as I suggested in my comment and solved for $\alpha$, and got $\alpha=3$. Is there another number that also works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial has roots $r=1$ and $r=3$ so the solution has to be something like $$T_n=1^n A+ 3^n B=A+ 3^n B$$ Using the conditions $$T_0=A+B=0$$ $$T_1=A+3B=2$$ gives two linear equations for $A$ and $B$; the solutions are $A=-1$, $B=1$. So, finally $$T_n=-1+3^n$$ If the value of $T_0$ and $T_1$ were not given, you would have obtained $$A=\frac{3{T_0}-{T_1}}{2} $$ $$B=\frac{{T_1}-{T_0}}{2}$$